# Translating a Unity 2D Code into 3D

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, physics

I got a small Script for a swinging Axe in 2D. Just like for example this one here:

[Dark Souls Swinging Axe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpCdL.jpg)

My problem is, that I do not know how to translate the 2D code into 3D. My object got a Rigidbody and a Hinge Joint (for swinging Physics) attached. The

```
Rigidbody.angularVelocity
```

needs to get a Vector3 instead of a float value.

My Code:

```
   Rigidbody rigid;
    float rangeToPush = 0.3f;
    float velocity = 120;

    private void Start()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rigid.angularVelocity = Vector3.down * velocity;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.rotation.z > 0 &&
            transform.rotation.z < -rangeToPush &&
            rigid.angularVelocity.magnitude > 0 &&
            rigid.angularVelocity.magnitude < velocity)
        {
            rigid.angularVelocity = Vector3.down * velocity;
        }

        else if (transform.rotation.z < 0 &&
            transform.rotation.z > rangeToPush &&
            rigid.angularVelocity.magnitude < 0 &&
            rigid.angularVelocity.magnitude > -120)
        {
            rigid.angularVelocity = Vector3.down * -velocity;
        }
    }
```

The things missing are the value for

```
data.Rigid.angularVelocity = ?Vector3?
```

instead of my float value and obviously my two last if-statements are wrong, i have

```
if( /* the other statements .. && */ data.Rigid.angularVelocity > 0 && data.Rigid.angularVelocity < data.RigidVelocity)
```

and I need to convert it into 3D.

Thanks a lot for help!

Edit: I tried to use

```
data.Rigid.angularVelocity = Vector3.down * data.RigidVelocity;
```

and for my if-statements

```
Rigid.angularVelocity.magnitude
```

but this is gonna swing for a limited time, not endless. So maybe I have to change a value in the Data Script or I have to use something else instead of magnitude ... I do not know

Comment: i would just animate it with Animation or move with script and AnimationCurve..

Comment: Yes I just thought about animating it. But I feel better with scripting, that's why I asked :)

Comment: Pick your flat plane x/y or y/z and implement that way, ignore the left over axis. Or keep 2d stuff, don't display it and pipe the transforms to 3d objects (probably inefficient)

Answer (score 2):

i finally got it. I removed the HingeJoint and used this code to make it swing endless:

```
    float speed = 0.4f; // Speed
    float amplitude = 70; // How far can it swing?

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Sin(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * Mathf.PI * speed) * amplitude)); // Swing
    }
```